# Apache Netbeans 12.0 Java Help Integration

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, netbeans-12

Java Help Integration does not work in NetBeans platform Application.

I am migrating from NetBeans 8.0 to Apache NetBeans 12.0.
It does not successfully build.

> An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
> Consult the following stack trace for details.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/help/search/Indexer
>
> C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\harness\common.xml:204: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-commits/201905.mbox/%3CJIRA.13144694.1520940769000.246483.1557827040280@Atlassian.JIRA%3E something to do with the `org-netbeans-modules-javahelp` and `javahelp` dependencies.

Comment: It does not work, even Netbean 12 IDE do not have link of Help Content under Help Menu.

Answer (score 1):

Since the transfer of Netbeans to Apache **JavaHelp** was removed from Netbeans due to lincensing issues. To my knowledge JavaHelp has been removed due to its GPL license. Apache projects cannot distribute GPL.

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Donation+changes+to+be+reviewed  (search for javahelp)
- https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/a3c047a068bd7f99a3c515cd89e2a72645965ae799c3be5a8b9739f0@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E